# AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I wrote an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for updating the column `abc_xyz` of table `ABC`. The trigger should fire when somebody tries to update the column `ans_mode` of the same table. The default value of `abc_xyz` is `0`. The trigger should update it to `1`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER switchtrigger
   AFTER UPDATE OF ans_mode
   ON ABC
BEGIN
   UPDATE ABC
      SET abc_xyz = 1
   WHERE abc_xyz= 0 AND ;
END;
```

I am trying to write an `AND` condition so as to update only those particular rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger above is a statement trigger instead of a row trigger.  IMO it would be better to have this be a BEFORE UPDATE row trigger so that you can just change the :NEW value to the value you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SWITCHTRIGGER
   BEFORE UPDATE OF ANS_MODE ON ABC
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ABC_XYZ = 0 THEN
    :NEW.ABC_XYZ := 1;
  END IF;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Jarvis,
I tried writing a row trigger , but was getting Mutating table error as updation was done in the same table.
The default value of ABC_XYZ is 0. So the IF condtion mentioned in the query will update all the rows right??
I need only to udate those rows , where the user/somebody has made the change.

Comment: In a row trigger you cannot execute any SQL statement which accesses the table on which the table is declared - that's what the "mutating table" error is all about.  An ON UPDATE row trigger will only be invoked for rows which are actually changed according to the declared condition so this trigger will only affect those rows where ABC.ANS_MODE has been changed.  I suggest youwrite a little code and test this out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks Jarvis. I tested and it worked.
what difference does it make if I use a After update trigger ( Other than it fires after the update )

Comment: In an AFTER trigger you can count on the fact that the data available in the trigger is exactly as it will be stored in the database.  BEFORE triggers are allowed to modify data before it's stored in the database.  AFTER triggers are useful any time the code needs to be sure the data is stable and exactly as it will be in the database - for example, when archiving data.